# Julia: how to randlomy create vector of size n having only specific numbers?

Tags: julia

I'd like to create a vector of random number of size `Dl =500` and only have number 1 ot 2 or 3. I did

```
v = fill(0, Dl) # create a vector of size 500 filled with zeros
v[rand(1:length(v), Dl)] .= rand(1:3, Dl)
```

However, I see that some numbers are 0. I have 0,1,2,3 not jsu t 1,2,3. What is the issue?

Comment: Your problem here is that you are indexing 10 RANDOM locations. Some of them will be the same and some will never be touched. Instead you should remove the random function for indexing. Simply put ```v[1:length(v)] .= rand(1:3, Dl)``` and your problem will vanish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are both randomizing target indices and their values.

Doing:

```
v .= rand(1:3, Dl)
```

is enough to replace values of `v` in-place with fresh random values.

Altenatively, you could just write:

```
v = rand(1:3, Dl)
```

(without the `fill` part) to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this is what you are trying to achieve.

```
Dl =500
v = fill(0, Dl) # create a vector of size 500 filled with zeros
v[1:Dl] .= rand(1:3, Dl)
```

Your issue can be explained down below with a smaller set of ten:

```
Dl = 10
v = fill(0, Dl) # create a vector of size 500 filled with zeros
v[rand(1:length(v), Dl)] .= rand(1:3, Dl)
```

Breaking this down into components we can see you have:

```
Dl = 10
v = fill(0, Dl) # create a vector of size 500 filled with zeros
problem = rand(1:length(v), Dl)
v[problem] .= rand(1:3, Dl)
```

So `problem` becomes a vector of size `Dl` with at each index of `problem` is a value between 1 and `Dl` or `length(v)`. So a possible set is [1,2,6,5,8,5,10,2,4,4]. So you are now setting the index' at 2,5,4 more than once, 1,6,8,10 only once and then never touch index 3,7,9.Because you initialized your vector to all zeros they will remain at zero in indices 3,7,9.